Dart date time difference in minutes
Using Dart, I am getting a UTC date from an API, and trying to get the difference in minutes to the current date.
void main() {   
    
    DateTime chkDate = DateTime.parse("2024-04-20 23:10:06");
    DateTime now = DateTime.now().toUtc();
    final difference = now.difference(chkDate).inMinutes;
  
    print(chkDate);
    print(now);
    print(difference.toString());  
}

Whatever I do, the minutes is always at an hour too much (I am in GMT time, UTC+1) so am pretty sure it something to do with this, but I cannot work it out.
This is the output using the code above at 00:21 local time. It display the now date as UTC, but the difference is still 71, when I need 1
2024-04-20 23:10:06.000
2024-04-20 23:21:11.578Z
71


You need to convert both times to the same time zone before comparison.
71 minutes is the one-hour offset added by your local time zone (UTC+1), which wasn't accounted for when parsing chkDate. A 1-minute difference would be returned if you compare the same hour value.
Make sure to parse the date in UTC if the API returns the date in UTC. Try adding Z to the timestamp from the API, see my example below (simplified, you may need to do it differently):
DateTime chkDate = DateTime.parse("2024-04-20 23:10:06Z");

